# What are these these weird lines and how do I remove them?

Tags: shrinkwrap

I have a long cylinder as the handle and used more short cylinders as wrapping. I've used shrink wrap modifier on those smaller cylinders (also applied it later on) to get them look like wrapping. The problem is these lines appear when zoomed out, initially I thought they probably won't come in the rendered image/video but they are coming. They are not visible when zoomed in but only when zoomed out. Can anyone help me identify why they are coming and how do I remove them? Thanks in advance.

Ps. This is my first question, apologies if I didn't ask the question properly.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: search for z-fighting here...

Comment: Thanks Chris. The issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

[What settings influence Z-Fighting in files with identical geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204511/what-settings-influence-z-fighting-in-files-with-identical-geometry)
This question helped me find the solution to my problem. Not knowing what to call the issue led me to search using various terms like glitch, flickering, weird lines, etc., and it just made me go mad. So this issue is called Z fight, thanks for the comment Chris.

I fixed the issue by changing the difference between clip start and clip end to be 1000. It was more than 6000 before the change.